# How to drive this SICP sample function?

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

Please show me how to drive the `stream-withdraw` function from SICP [section 3.5.5](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#%_sec_3.5.5) correctly.

```
(define (stream-cons a b) (cons a (delay b)))
(define (stream-car s) (car s))
(define (stream-cdr s) (force (cdr s)))

(define (stream-withdraw balance amount-stream)
  (stream-cons
   balance
   (stream-withdraw (- balance (stream-car amount-stream)) (stream-cdr amount-stream))))

; Calling stream-withdraw in the following manner raises an exception.
(stream-withdraw 100 (stream-cons 0 0))
; car: contract violation
; expected: pair?
; given: 0
```

I assume `amount-stream` should be constructed in a different way.

Comment: I've found in SICP that stream-cons must be a special form. Let me modify my question: What is the proper way to construct amount-stream? Also, I'd like to see the typical way this stream would be used in subsequent calls to stream-withdraw in the functional way while the user enters his new withdrawals. I still don't see the key element in using a stream to avoid local state.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this definition:

```
(define-syntax stream-cons
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((stream-cons head tail)
     (cons head (delay tail)))))
```

Given that `stream-cons` requires different evaluation rules, it can't be implemented as a normal procedure - hence, we use a macro. For the same reason, the `delay` primitive is also a macro.

Comment: Thank you for your reply which answers my original question. Could you perhaps outline for an OO programmer how streams could be applied in a simple read loop to manage the balance for a single person? I just have no idea how functional programming solves problems like that without assignment.

Comment: Perhaps by creating a stream of values for the balance? I'm a bit dusty on this chapter of SICP, but IIRC this is explained in the book

Comment: It was my hope that the chapter about streams would help me in understanding this issue. Unfortunately the application of the balance stream is not shown. When you say 'a stream of values for the balance', it sounds to me as if there's one stream that collects the withdrawals but then it should be mutable, shouldn't it? I'm really confused.

Comment: The stream would record the whole history of balance values, but only the last one would be the current

Comment: How do you retain the stream and extend it with the withdrawals entered by the user? The stream is unmutable, is it not?

Comment: You can mutate the variable that holds it, not the stream itself

Comment: To mutate the variable that holds the stream would require assignment. The book described using streams as a way to avoid local state and assignment. I must still be missing something.

Comment: @AttilaKaroly the stream returned is the new balance. If you make a procedure that somehow gets values and add it to the bank procedure and keep that in consecutive recursions it will be a new variable every time but it would work as if it were mutated.

Comment: @Sylwester, could you sketch for me in a few lines of code what you describe as 'a procedure that somehow gets values...', please? That 'somehow' is exactly what this novice Schemer is eager to see.

Answer (score 1):

Streams are not really replacements for mutating state. It's a way of delaying evaluation.

An example:

```scm
(define one-to-million
  (let loop ((n #e1e6) (acc '()))
    (if (zero? n)
        acc
        (loop (- n 1) (cons n acc)))))

(define (list-square lst)
  (map (lambda (x) (* x x)) lst))

(define (list-double lst)
  (map (lambda (x) (+ x x)) lst))

(define (list-sqrt lst)
  (map sqrt lst))

(take (list-sqrt (list-double (list-square one-to-million))) 5)
; ==> (1.4142135623730951 2.8284271247461903 
;      4.242640687119285 5.656854249492381 7.0710678118654755)
```

If you look at what happnes here you'll see that it makes a new list of million elements at each step of the way and in the end just uses the first 5 results. A stream version:

```scm
(define (stream-take s n)
  (if (zero? n)
      '()
      (cons (stream-car s)
            (stream-take (stream-cdr s) (- n 1)))))

(define (integers-starting-from n)
  (stream-cons n (integers-starting-from (+ n 1))))

(define from1 (integers-starting-from 1)) ; infinite stream!

(define (stream-map proc stream)
  (stream-cons (proc (stream-car stream))
               (stream-map proc (stream-cdr stream))))

(define (stream-square stream)
  (stream-map (lambda (x) (* x x)) stream))

(define (stream-double stream)
  (stream-map (lambda (x) (+ x x)) stream))

(define (stream-sqrt stream)
  (stream-map sqrt stream))

(stream-take (stream-sqrt (stream-double (stream-square from1))) 5)
; ==> (1.4142135623730951 2.8284271247461903 
;      4.242640687119285 5.656854249492381 7.0710678118654755)
```

In this version it would do each step for the first element in the result before starting the square of the second element, but the structure fo the program looks as if you do first the square, then the double etc.

A perhaps modern approach of this that uses lists but does all steps in for each element eagerly are transducers and generators.

As for keeping state you don't need streams for that. You can make a procedure that recurse until it's finished:

```scm
(let loop ((state '()) (input input))
  (if (input-empty? input)
      state ; finished
      (loop (process-input (input-get input) state)
            (input-next input))))
```

Now we can give this a totally functional implementation:

```scm
(define input '(1 2 3 4))
(define input-get car)
(define input-next cdr)
(define input-empty? null?)
(define process-input cons)
```

Or we could make it a dirty side effect version:

```scm
(define input (current-input-port))
(define input-get read-line)
(define input-next values) ; just return the port
(define input-empty? (lambda (x) (eq? (peek-byte x) eof))) ; check if there is more to read
(define process-input cons)
```

Comment: @AttilaKaroly You asked for an example and in the end of my answer I have one. I don't use streams in that example to show that streams are not a requirement to "keep"/"update" state however know that requesting user input or displaying output are side effects and thus ruins the pureness.